# What does "I need to rant" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Could you possibly explain to me what could  "I need to (personally) rant" mean?

Does it mean like "I have some problems and I feel nervous or down and I have to share my problems with other people so that I can relax and relieve."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the dictionary ([OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rant)) & you'll find that *rant* has a stronger connotation than simply *sharing one's problems*.

> Speak or shout at length in a wild, impassioned way:

Normally, I'd use it to describe someone who's *complaining* rather than relieving whatever burden their problems have brought. So, "I need to rant" could have a slight negative connotation depending on the context.

Comment: Indeed, someone who needs to rant is probably angry but powerless to fix their problem.  They are frustrated.

Comment: Thank you Jerson Zuleta and Jason Patterson.You are very helpful.I heard a meaning of this word kind of shouting angrily or whining for a meal at a restaurant maybe but now I learnt it could be used in confusing and frustrating situations

Answer (score 5):

Often, I think when someone tells you that they need to rant, they are letting you know that they want to complain, and will feel better just by having complained. They do not want you to help them fix the problem. They do not want you to come up with a solution. They just want you to listen. Sometimes we might stay that they want you to lend a sympathetic ear. This means they are looking for someone to listen and understand their frustration.

Answer (score 0):

More often than not, the speaker is saying, or rather, giving a warning that they are about to vent or blow off some steam and it is not anything directed personally at you.  Yet, at the risk of otherwise appearing like the crazy man down on the street shouting at the sky, they will proceed to do the same with you as their captive audience.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers.